# How to load this category in desire format in Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have `Category` model like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name="children")
    description = HTMLField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I want list them like this:

Category without parent in Navigation bar like this:

```
Category.objects.filter(parent=None)
```

Let's say parent == SuperParent.

Now I want to load other categories which has parents like this in a widget:

```
Widget Box 1:

Category Parent (children of SuperParent):
   Child1 of parent 
   Child2 of parent 
   .. and so on

Widget Box 2

Category Parent(another name)(Children of SuperParent):
    Childs
```

How to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Something like a template (say obj is the widget): `Name: {{obj.name}}<br>Category: {{obj.category}}<br>Parent category: {{obj.category.parent}}<br><ul>{%for cat in obj.category.children%}<li>cat.name</li>{%endfor%}</ul>` ?

Answer (score 0):

> p_cat = Category.objects.filter(parent=None)

**template**

> {% for cat in p_cat %}
>
> {{ cat.name }}
>
> {% for ch_cat in cat.children.all %}
>
> - {{ ch_cat.name }}
>
> {% endfor %}
>
> {% endfor %}